# click gallery without lightbox in drupal (multiple cck images)

Tags: javascript, drupal, view, module, gallery

Hi I want to find a module or a js script to embed to drupal that can show me all the images uploaded to a node (CCK fields as images) and when I click on one to load that image as the highlighted one (big picture) just like in the following layout. 
Can anyone tell me if such a module exist?
[image]

or

[image]

an image has to be loaded by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the [Fancy Slide module](http://drupal.org/project/fancy_slide) can do what you're looking for. If not, there are other [Rotator/Slideshow modules](http://drupal.org/node/418616) that may.

Comment: p.s. - You may also want to check out the Drupal Answers Beta site. The more people who use it, the better chance it has of making it past beta: http://drupal.stackexchange.com

Comment: oh, that's a great ideea of a site 10x :)